# Variable in the JavaScript in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    Page.GetType(),
    "INFORMATION",
    @"PopupMessage(""INFORMATION"", ""Data was created successfully"", false);",
    true);
```

The code above show the JavaScript code in C# code behind

What I want to do is add the variable to the message

but I used this code which does not work:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    Page.GetType(),
    "INFORMATION",
    @"PopupMessage(""INFORMATION"", """+Data+" was created successfully"", false);",
    true);
```

It throws error:

> Error CS1501 No overload for method 'RegisterStartupScript' takes 5 arguments

Does someone know how to make it work?

Comment: The Data is a String type data after add "+Data+" the code fail to run .
It show CS1003: Syntax Error, ',' expected

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1501 No overload for method 'RegisterStartupScript' takes 5 arguments 

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1003 Syntax error, ',' expected

Comment: That `@` only applies to the string literal immediately following it, not to any other literals in the same expression - see David's answer

Comment: Ya haha It's work new to C# 
Thank you Hans Kesting too~~

Answer (score 3):

This string literal is a syntax error:

```
" was created successfully"", false);"
```

One of the things the [verbatim identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) does for a string is change the way double-quotes are interpreted.  Without it, double-quotes need to be escaped.  But *with* it, escaping doesn't work (because it's a verbatim string) so a special consideration needs to be made for double-quotes.  To add them to a string you need to "double" them.

This is why your other string literal works as expected:

```
@"PopupMessage(""INFORMATION"", """
```

To achieve the same thing in the failing string literal, use the verbatim identifier again:

```
@" was created successfully"", false);"
```

Comment: OMG! It's Works!!
Thank You David ~~
Thank you so much~

Comment: You can mark it as answer if it works for you